# JavaScript (EMCAScript) global variables guaranteed across all runtime environments

Tags: javascript

Because JavaScript code generally gains usefulness through interaction with an execution environment, most contexts will place specific variables (and functions) in a global scope, to expose data and functionality from the environment. For example, in a web browser, the `window` object allows JavaScript code included in a web page to interact with the browser context. However, the variable is not required by the language generally, and many JavaScript engines would not necessarily provide a similar object, due to its meaning not applying to the environment.

What variables are in the set that represents a "lowest common denominator", defined for the language itself, of those guaranteed to occur in global scope?

What advice is available for defining context-specific conventions that may durably protect against collisions?

Comment: Probably [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) is about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Everything [the spec says must be on the global object](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object) must be there. JS doesn’t have a standard way to write output and read input like other languages have (via STDIN and STDOUT); _that’s_ the job of the specific environment and implementation.

Comment: By the way, a host environment will define _properties_ on the global object (also called “global properties”), _not variables_.

Comment: @Sebastian... The difference being that properties are immutably bound?

Comment: @brainchild No, they’re not immutably bound (at least not all of them), but in some contexts the difference between variables and properties is important to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them [defined in the specification as *properties of the global object*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-global-object). They are currently (in ECMAScript 2022):

> `globalThis` `Infinity` `NaN` `undefined` `eval` `isFinite` `isNaN` `parseFloat` `parseInt` `decodeURI` `decodeURIComponent` `encodeURI` `encodeURIComponent` `Array` `ArrayBuffer` `BigInt` `BigInt64Array` `BigUint64Array` `Boolean` `DataView` `Date` `Error` `EvalError` `FinalizationRegistry` `Float32Array` `Float64Array` `Function` `Int8Array` `Int16Array` `Int32Array` `Map` `Number` `Object` `Promise` `Proxy` `RangeError` `ReferenceError` `RegExp` `Set` `SharedArrayBuffer` `String` `Symbol` `SyntaxError` `TypeError` `Uint8Array` `Uint8ClampedArray` `Uint16Array` `Uint32Array` `URIError` `WeakMap` `WeakRef` `WeakSet` `Atomics` `JSON` `Math` `Reflect`

However, none of these are to "*gain usefulness through interaction with an execution environment*". That goes above "*the language itself*", and there is no further standard for that, the environments in which ECMAScript code runs are just too different - from microcontrollers over the web to desktop and server applications. The web however does have a lot of standards, for the competing implementations to follow, and non-web JS environments usually follow them as well where it makes sense for them, so you could consider HTML5 to be the greatest common divisor.

Comment: Also, multipage link: https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/multipage/global-object.html#sec-global-object

Comment: And then there is the case of (optional) ECMA addons that may be worth a note, like the ECMA-402 Internationalization API.

Comment: @Kaiido The order is taken from the spec as-is.

Comment: @Kaiido Good call about addons, are there any others than ECMA-402? It introduces only a single global: `Intl`

Comment: About the order: I see, so it's alphabetic, but in 4 categories "values", "functions", "constructors" and "others"... Maybe it's fine as is in your answer, maybe adding back those categories would help, maybe sorting the whole... your call. Regarding addons, I'm not sure where to get a potential full list, I just remembered `Intl` and saw it was not in the list. Doing a quick "find in page" I only see ECMA-402 though.

Comment: The purpose of the question ultimately was to find a way to avoid collisions between entries into the global namespace from the core interpreter versus the application context. With addons, this issue is complicated further, and would be good to see addressed.

Comment: @brainchild By "application context", do you mean the runtime environment or the user code?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the application hosting the JS engine. The JS code is not relevant, I think, for the issue. A user who needs an value simply should not assign another to the same name.

Comment: @brainchild If you're embedding an engine in your application, just check the docs of the version you are using. You're unlikely to introduce globals that will conflict with the language. Additions to the language are usually screened for compatibility with existing implementations, you can also [follow the active proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). If you're unsure, just put everything in a namespace object identified by the name of your applications.

Comment: It's a matter of being "future proof". Even use of a single namespace must be bound to one name in global scope.

Comment: Well if you call it `BrainChild`, you can be certain that ECMAScript will never standardise that :-)

Comment: And if you _really_ care, you can observe the new proposals and always chime in with _“No, don’t call this feature `BrainChild`!”_. In your recent question you said that some environments that TC39 tests with are _“off the radar of standards bodies”_ — Why not be _on_ the radar, then?